# return more than 1 value pl/sql function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to enable a user to input values and return more than one value using pl/sql function, I managed to return only one value and couldnt promote a user to input values. I need for Customer 5 to increase order from 30 to 200. Enable the user to type in:

1) The number 4 for customer_ID and 
2) 100 for the updated quantity.

and printout the output before and after the change, somththing like this
..

```
Enter value for customer_id: 4
old   7:   l_customer_id :=&customer_ID;
new   7:   l_customer_id :=4;
Enter value for new_quantity: 520
old   9:   l_new_quantity :=&new_quantity;
new   9:   l_new_quantity :=520;
Old quangtity: 100
New quantity: 520
Quantity changed from 100 to 520 (+420)
```

The code I have but returns only the old quantity value

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_sales
( 
  p_customer_id IN sales.customer_id%type,
  p_product_id IN sales.product_id%type,
  p_new_quantity IN sales.quantity%type
)
RETURN sales.quantity%type
AS
  l_old_quantity sales.quantity%type;
BEGIN
  SELECT quantity
  INTO l_old_quantity
  FROM sales
  WHERE customer_id = p_customer_id
  AND product_id = p_product_id;

  UPDATE sales
  SET quantity = p_new_quantity
  WHERE customer_id = p_customer_id
  AND product_id = p_product_id;

  RETURN l_old_quantity;
END;
/

DECLARE
  l_old_quantity sales.quantity%type;
BEGIN
  l_old_quantity := update_sales(5, 4, 200);
  dbms_output.put_line('Quantity was ' || l_old_quantity);
END;
/
```

Product table

```
Create table sales (customer_ID number(10), product_ID number(10), quantity number(10));

INSERT INTO sales (customer_ID, product_ID, quantity) Values(3,1,23);
INSERT INTO sales (customer_ID, product_ID, quantity) Values(1,2,34);
INSERT INTO sales (customer_ID, product_ID, quantity) Values(1,3,654);
INSERT INTO sales (customer_ID, product_ID, quantity) Values(3,7,32);
INSERT INTO sales (customer_ID, product_ID, quantity) Values(4,3,23);
INSERT INTO sales (customer_ID, product_ID, quantity) Values(3,3,111);
INSERT INTO sales (customer_ID, product_ID, quantity) Values(5,4,6);
```

Please advice

Comment: What are the values you want to return other than `l_old_quantity`?

Comment: I need to return l_customer_id and l_new_quantity please. Thanks in advance

Comment: if we could go this far as the output I declared up. it would be amazing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, It is not possible to return more than one variable from function.

However, you have two options as follows:

**Option 1:** 
Not recommended with functions:

You can use `OUT` type in your function parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_sales
( 
  p_customer_id_in IN sales.customer_id%type,
  p_product_id_in IN sales.product_id%type,
  p_new_quantity_in IN  sales.quantity%type
  p_customer_id_out OUT sales.customer_id%type,
  p_product_id_out OUT sales.product_id%type,
  p_old_quantity_out OUT sales.quantity%type
)
....
--The remaining of your function
```

For `customer_id` you can use `IN OUT` type for one variable if you want to.

And then when you call it, you use something like this:

```
v_result:=update_sales(p_customer_id_in => 5,  p_product_id_in => 4, p_new_quantity_in => 200,  p_customer_id_out => v1_out,  p_product_id_out => v2_out,  p_new_quantity_out => v3_out );
```

**Option 2:**
Use `record` type
To do this, you need first to define type contains the three variables you want to return as follows:

```
TYPE new_type is record(l_customer_id sales.customer_id%type, l_old_quantity sales.quantity%type, l_new_quantity  sales.quantity%type);
```

Then you can use it in your function as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_sales
( 
 p_customer_id IN sales.customer_id%type,
 p_product_id IN sales.product_id%type,
 p_new_quantity IN sales.quantity%type
)
RETURN new_type AS 

new_type_variable newtype;
....

BEGIN
--You can refer to the fields of the records using (.) 
-- e.g., new_type_variable.l_customer_id

 RETURN new_type_variable ;
END;
```

**Complete function based on the first approach**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_sales
( 
  p_customer_id_in IN sales.customer_id%type,
  p_product_id_in IN sales.product_id%type,
  p_new_quantity_in IN  sales.quantity%type,
  p_customer_id_out OUT sales.customer_id%type,
  p_product_id_out OUT sales.product_id%type,
  p_old_quantity_out OUT sales.quantity%type
)
RETURN sales.quantity%type
AS
  l_old_quantity sales.quantity%type;
BEGIN
  SELECT quantity
  INTO p_old_quantity_out
  FROM sales
  WHERE customer_id = p_customer_id_in
  AND product_id = p_product_id_in;

  UPDATE sales
  SET quantity = p_new_quantity_in
  WHERE customer_id = p_customer_id_in
  AND product_id = p_product_id_in;

  RETURN l_old_quantity;
END;
/
```

**Testing**

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_TEST(a varchar2(100));

DECLARE 
V_RESULT NUMBER;
v1_out  sales.customer_id%type;
v2_out  sales.product_id%type;
v3_out  sales.quantity%type;
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(10000);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TEST');

v_result:=update_sales
(
  p_customer_id_in => 5,
  p_product_id_in => 4,
  p_new_quantity_in => 200,
  p_customer_id_out => v1_out,
  p_product_id_out => v2_out,
  p_old_quantity_out => v3_out
 );
  INSERT INTO TEMP_TEST VALUES ('p_customer_id_out = ' ||v1_out);
  INSERT INTO TEMP_TEST VALUES ('p_product_id_out = '||v2_out);
  INSERT INTO TEMP_TEST VALUES ('p_old_quantity_out = '||v3_out);
  COMMIT;

END;
/

SELECT * FROM TEMP_TEST;
```

Result:

```
p_customer_id_out =     
p_product_id_out =     
p_old_quantity_out = 200
```

Because in your function, you only assigned value to `p_old_quantity_out`

Comment: Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

SQL> show error;
Errors for FUNCTION UPDATE_SALES:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
14/3     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
18/20    PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "P_PRODUCT_ID": invalid identifier
20/3     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
23/20    PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "P_PRODUCT_ID": invalid identifier
SQL>

Comment: SQL> TYPE new_type is record(l_customer_id sales.customer_id%type, l_old_quantity sales.quantity%type, l_new_quantity  sales.quantity%type);
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "TYPE new_t..." - rest of line ignored.

Comment: @Chaz There is no `P_PRODCUT_ID` in my code, I renamed it to `P_PRODCUT_ID_IN' and `P_PRODCUT_ID_OUT`, amend the rest of the function accordingly. As for the second error, defining a type is not SQL statement, it's a PL/SQL that needs to be enclosed within BEING & END; kewords

Comment: I'm confused where to put the p_product_in and P_product_out instead.. shall I replace p_product_ID with P_PRODCUT_ID_IN and product_id with P_product_out? 
Thanks

Comment: @Chaz use p_product_id_in instead of p_product_id. You can use p_product_id_out wherever you want to return that value. For example, you can use within statement like this `SELECT product  INTO p_product_id_out  FROM sales  WHERE customer_id = p_customer_id
  AND product_id = p_product_id;`. p_product_id_out is one of the three values wanted to return from your function.

Comment: its not working with me :(((( can you please update the full code .. I really need it .. thanks in advance :(

Comment: I tried the other approach with begin and end and got an error too

Comment: SQL> begin
  2  TYPE new_type is record(l_customer_id sales.customer_id%type, l_old_quantity sales.quantity%type, l_new_quantity  sales.quantity%type);
  3  end;
  4  /
TYPE new_type is record(l_customer_id sales.customer_id%type, l_old_quantity sales.quantity%type, l_new_quantity  sales.quantity%type);
     *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 6:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "NEW_TYPE" when expecting one of the
following:
:= . ( @ % ;

Comment: @Chaz There is running code I've added above. Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm getting this error.. please advice
v_result:=update_sales
          *
ERROR at line 10:
ORA-06550: line 10, column 11:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'UPDATE_SALES'
ORA-06550: line 10, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: @Chaz I've replicated your table and tested the function, no errors whatsoever returned. Unless you have changed something, everything should goes well. Otherwise, you need to check what you've changed

Comment: Thanks but you missed to declare quantity out which caused an error as follow : 15/8     PLS-00201: identifier 'P_NEW_QUANTITY_OUT' must be declared

Comment: @Chaz Thanks I've updated it, it actually declared correctly, but the one in `select into` statement should be `p_old_quantity_out`

Answer (score 0):

In your example I do actually not understand why you need to return the new quantity as this is an argument that you actually submit to your function.

I would nevertheless just use a procedure instead of a function and return as many OUT parameters as needed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_sales
( p_customer_id IN sales.customer_id%type,
, p_product_id IN sales.product_id%type,
, p_new_quantity IN sales.quantity%type,
, p_old_quantity OUT sales.quantity%type
, p_transaction_date OUT DATE /* just as an example */
)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT quantity
  INTO p_old_quantity
  FROM sales
  WHERE customer_id = p_customer_id
  AND product_id = p_product_id;

  UPDATE sales
  SET quantity = p_new_quantity
  WHERE customer_id = p_customer_id
  AND product_id = p_product_id;

  p_transaction_date := SYSDATE;
END;
/

DECLARE
  l_old_quantity sales.quantity%type;
  l_transaction_date DATE;
BEGIN
  update_sales(5, 4, 200, l_old_quantity, l_current_date);
  dbms_output.put_line('Quantity was ' || l_old_quantity);
  dbms_output.put_line('Transaction date was ' || l_transaction_date);
END;
/
```